# Spring application not starting - "Parameter 0 of constructor required a bean of type N that could not be found" error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm new to Spring Boot, I'm using it with Hibernate in an Java application (without JPA).

I have a `CallbackController` class which receives and handles callbacks from a third party service - the data of the received message are read and have to be stored in the payments table (of a MySQL database).

`CallbackController` has a method where a call to a method `storePaymentInfo()` from a class `PaymentsRepo` is made, which handles the data storing.

How to do this correctly? `PaymentsRepo` is annotated with `@Component`  and has a constructor which accepts `PaymentDao` as an input parameter. CallbackController's constructor accepts `PaymentsRepo` as an input parameter. The app is not starting because of an error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.chatgpt_nn.repository.PaymentsRepo required a bean of type 'com.chatgpt_nn.dao.PaymentDao' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.chatgpt_nn.dao.PaymentDao' in your configuration.
```

CallbackController.java

```java
    @Controller
    public class CallbackController {

    private final PaymentsRepo paymentsRepo;
    private String redirectCode;

    @Autowired
    public CallbackController(PaymentsRepo paymentsRepo) {
        this.paymentsRepo = paymentsRepo;
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        System.out.println("Host visited");
        return "index";
    }

    public String getRedirectCode() {
        return redirectCode;
    }


    @PostMapping("/callback-payment") // Add this for POST requests
    public String handleCallback(@RequestBody String requestBody,
                                 @RequestParam(name = "datetime") String dateTime,
                                 @RequestParam(name = "operation_id") String operationId,
                                 @RequestParam(name = "sender") String walletNumber,
                                 @RequestParam(name = "sender") String label,
                                 @RequestParam(name = "amount") String amount,
                                 @RequestParam(name = "currency") String currency,
                                 @RequestParam(name = "sha1_hash") String sha1Hash) {
        // Store the data in Payments table
        paymentsRepo.storePaymentInfo(amount, operationId, walletNumber, dateTime);
        return "redirect:/redirected-page";
        }
    }
```

PaymentsRepo.java

```java
    @Component
    public class PaymentsRepo {

    private PaymentDao paymentDao;

    @Autowired
    public PaymentsRepo(PaymentDao paymentDao) {
        this.paymentDao = paymentDao;
    }

    public Payment storePaymentInfo(String amount, String operationId, String walletNumber, String dateTime) {
        Payment payment = new Payment(amount, operationId, walletNumber, dateTime);
        paymentDao.addPayment(payment);
        return payment;
        }
    }
```

PaymentDao.java

```java
    public interface PaymentDao {
    void addPayment(Payment payment);

    Payment getPaymentById(int id);

    List<Payment> getAllPayments();
    }
```

PaymentDaoImpl.java

```java
    public class PaymentDaoImpl implements PaymentDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public void addPayment(Payment payment) {
        entityManager.persist(payment);
    }

    @Override
    public Payment getPaymentById(int id) {
        return entityManager.find(Payment.class, id);
        }
    }
```

Main.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        TelegramBotsApi botsApi = new TelegramBotsApi(DefaultBotSession.class);
        botsApi.registerBot(new GptTelegramBot());

        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

Spring/Hibernate dependencies:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <!--<version>6.1.1</version>-->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <!--<version>6.1.1</version>-->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        <!--<version>3.2.0</version>-->
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Your `PaymentDaoImpl` is missing the `@Component` annotation

Comment: Please don't ask a different question after your first question has been answered.

Comment: This wasn't a different question, your solution isn't working

Answer (score 0):

As @Sören has stated, your paymentDaoImpl has not been annotated with @Component. This means your bean has not been created in the Spring environment and cannot be used.

Comment: This is not working - after annotating it with @Component  I get another error: "A component required a bean of type 'jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' that could not be found. Action: Consider defining a bean of type jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' in your configuration."

Comment: You need to add the following dependencies into your pom. <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-b180830.0359</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your class `PayementDaoImpl` is missing something to become a bean in order to be injected.

Putting the tag `@Component`, `@Service` or `@Bean` will make the class `PayementDaoImpl` a spring bean that would be able to be autowired and injected into your `PaymentsRepo`. I think `@Componnent` will be the most appropriated here:

```
@Component
public class PaymentDaoImpl implements PaymentDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public void addPayment(Payment payment) {
        entityManager.persist(payment);
    }

    @Override
    public Payment getPaymentById(int id) {
        return entityManager.find(Payment.class, id);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've annotated it with @Component, but now I get another error: "A component required a bean of type 'jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' that could not be found. Action: Consider defining a bean of type jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' in your configuration."

Comment: This is another problem. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57227004/consider-defining-a-bean-of-type-entitymanagerfactory-spring-boot
You should get arround with adding `hibernate-entitymanager` and `javax.xml.bind` in your pom.xml.